"No such file or directory" when trying to start a process in a docker container during application runtime
I'm unable to reference an executable (.exe) from another .csproj when running an asp.net application in a docker container when attempting to start a System.Diagnostics.Process even though the .exe is in the container's directory but i still receive this error "An error occurred trying to start process '/ct.mediator.app/CTBot.exe' with working directory '/ct.mediator.app'. No such file or directory".
I've made sure to include the absolute path to the executable when the container is up, no luck, I've also tried to set the Directory during runtime by doing Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("/ct.mediator.app"); and to set the WorkingDirectory in the StartInfo but also no luck, I've been trying to get the expected behaviour of getting the application (CTMediator.dll) to find the referenced executable (CTBot.exe) during runtime to start the process, but no luck.
No permissions have been set to access/modify the files in the container.
Program.cs
var process = new Process()
{
 StartInfo = new("/ct.mediator.app/CTBot.exe", "argument1", "argument2")
 {
   WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
   RedirectStandardOutput = true
 }
};

process.Start();

Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /ct.mediator.app
EXPOSE 5212
EXPOSE 7195

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /ct.mediator.src
COPY ["Mediator/CTMediator.csproj", "Mediator/"]
COPY ["Shared/CTShared.csproj", "Shared/"]
COPY ["Bot/CTBot.csproj", "Bot/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Mediator/./CTMediator.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/ct.mediator.src/Mediator"
RUN dotnet build "./CTMediator.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /ct.mediator.app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./CTMediator.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /ct.mediator.app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /ct.mediator.app
COPY --from=publish /ct.mediator.app/publish .
COPY --from=build /ct.mediator.src/Bot/bin/Release/net8.0/CTBot.exe /ct.mediator.app/CTBot.exe
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CTMediator.dll"]

The folder during runtime
-ct.mediator.app
 - CTMediator.dll
 - CTBot.dll
 - CTBot.exe

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction as to why I can't reference the file during runtime. Thank you!

When you run the container, do you have any volume mappings?

Yes I do, the volume mappings are as followed:
- ${APPDATA}\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets          - ${USERPROFILE}\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https/ 

One thing I notice is that you use Linux style paths with forward slashes. But CTBot.exe looks like a Windows program. Are you running Windows containers or are you running Linux containers under WSL2?

I'm running a Linux container under WSL2, I'm sure using the Linux style path separators are appropriate in this case, but a good suggestion nonetheless

If you're running the container under WSL2, it's running in a Linux VM. And since containers use the host machine's OS kernel, I'm 99% sure that you can't run Windows programs in it. To run Windows programs under Docker, you need to run Docker on Windows and use Windows as the host.

Adding this line might be helpful:
RUN chmod +rx /ct.mediator.app/CTBot.exe
this is to ensure the file has execute permissions.
